# Doctrine ORM simple Join in a legacy DB

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I simply want to collect catrel datas to an base object.

I have a **legacy database**, they are missing some 'standards' like the auto increment **id** col.

In the @ORM\JoinColumn Statement i made various constellations to maching the id, nothing worked. What is the correct way?

When i make following, the catrels arraycollection subarray remains empty.

```php
<?php
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$a = $em->getRepository('MyvendorCoreBundle:Product')->find(26834);
dump($a);
```

Base objects stored table

```
CREATE TABLE "product" (
    "id" INT NOT NULL,
    "mrtype" VARCHAR(60) NULL,
    -- many, many other cols
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Catrel table

```
CREATE TABLE "productcatrel" (
    "id" INT NOT NULL,
    "catid" INT NOT NULL,
    "sorder" INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id", "catid")
);
```

```php
<?php
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Productcatrel", mappedBy="product")
 **/
private $catrels;

public function __construct() {
    $this->catrels = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getCaterls() {
    return $this->catrels;
}

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

// many, many other cols & getters/setters
```

```php
/**
 * Productcatrel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="productcatrel", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IX_productcatrel_sorder", columns={"sorder"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Productcatrel
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="catrels")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $product;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sorder", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $sorder;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="catid", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $catid;

// following getters/setters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code above was correct. I only couldn't access so the ArrayCollection content.

Finally after analizing the PeristentCollection class [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html#555) i could get the datas with **->toArray()** on the collection property.